# Merge date slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have made this year slicer in power bi. I want to merge every year before 2017 into one part of the slicer so essentially instead of having a slicer for every year from 1992-2023 I only want a slicer called 'before 2017' and 2017-2023. Is this possible and how is it done? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a Calculated Column and use that for your slicer.
Something like:

```
YearGroup = IF([YEAR] < 2017, "before 2017", "2017 - " & YEAR(TODAY()) )
```